# Unable to get javac to automatically recompile a source file

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I am experimenting with the `javac` command line options, in order to learn about the `-sourcepath` and `-classpath` options.  When I run `javac`, having tried four different command line options for it, I am unable to obtain a recompiled .class file.

Here is my folder structure.  Please note that due to testing, the Test.java file is located inside the "bat" folder, which is an admittedly odd location.

```
projects \ prj1 \ bat \ bat.bat
                        Test.java
                        Test.class   <--- unable to obtain recompiled file.

                  src \ Main.java
                        Main.class
```

The contents of my two .java test files are:

```
// Main.java, located in the src folder
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}

// Test.java, located in the bat folder
class Test {}
```

Regarding the execution of `javac` at the command prompt, here are four options that I have tried.  I've run these commands from a batch file called bat.bat, which is located inside the "bat" folder.

```
javac ..\src\Main.java                      (no sourcepath, no cp)
javac -sourcepath . ..\src\Main.java        (sourcepath)
javac -cp . ..\src\Main.java                (cp)
javac -sourcepath . -cp . ..\src\Main.java  (sourcepath, cp)
```

In all of these `javac` commands above, I am unable to obtain a recompiled .class file, for the Test.java file.  Is this because I have not edited the Test.java file, since initially compiling it?  Please note that I have no `CLASSPATH` environment variable set.  Thanks.

Comment: I use an IDE and it ensures that my code is re-compiled as needed without me even having to save the files.  Just type code and run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If class files are already present in the destination / output folder, `javac` will only recompile the source java file if it has been modified since the date/time of the class file.

If you want to recompile the source files, then first delete the *.class files before calling `javac`.